# A list with multi-select Checkbox on an Alert Dialog?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, android-checkbox

I have been trying to get a list with some 10-12 items having a checkbox each on an alert dialog (i.e. when my activity starts).
So far I have come up with the following code; it doesn't have the checkboxes in it.
So, how can I implement this? Any sample code or advice will be appreciated. 
Thanks

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"cat1","cat2","cat3" };
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Categories");
          builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            switch (item) {
            case 0:
             //handle item1
             break;
            case 1:
             //item2
             break;
            case 2:
             //item3
             break;
            default:
             break;
            }  }
          });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();
```

Comment: why are you complicating thing... simply inflate the custom xml in alert... thats it

Comment: @Amir Shah :Please have a look at the Answer. It was way simple than inflating a custom XML layout and then code on it.

Comment: Just look at my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348518/resetting-checkboxes-in-androids-alert-dialog/31120138#31120138

Everything works fine...:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set setSingleChoiceItems() methods in builder object instead of setItems like below.

```
 builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items , -1,
                      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    })
```

If you want to display multiple selection list dialog then you have to set setMultiChoiceItems() instead of setSingleChoiceItems with DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener in its argument

All things are mention in Developer.Android.com you can look for a [dialog help here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList)

Comment: Hi, Yes that did work. But I am not able to extract selected items out of it. Consider this: item1 and item2 was selected by user. After that user de-selected item1 and instead selected item3. So, here we finally have item2 and item 3 selected. Here's what I tried: `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
if(isChecked){
//Toast for testing
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User selected " + items[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}}` Now, if I try to fill an array of items selected inside "onClick" method then it is not what I want to achieve. Thanks

Comment: do you want multiple selection enable or single selection ??

Comment: I need Multiselection. nvm I figured it out. The Link is what I should've read thoroughly before posting here. Finally, can you give me a hint on how can I work for a single checkbox on selecting it will select all the item's checkboxes automatically?

Comment: sorry for that, no idea, i have to look out

Comment: np. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend not to use complicated custom view in alert dialog.
Better use start activity for result for this.
In manifest set android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog" for your dialog activity

Answer (score 0):

As rajpara said, but I don't forget to have less complexity in your code by replacing your switch to items[which].toString();

Comment: Make it comment please.

Comment: please move this to a comment on rajpara, this way it'll be part of the answer